# Recommended machine learning method to solve my problem in sequence prediction

Tags: machine-learning, learning

I am pretty new to most algorithms and with there being so many out there, it is hard to choose as a beginner which one to use. Therefore, I am looking for some recommendations here. The problem is as follows: assume different series of treatments [T1, T2, T3] for a person. Now, every person can have a different set of treatments. My goal is to use the given data (so all the sets of completed treatment arrays) and predict the next treatment sequence for a new patient, which let's say is halfway through with its pathway.

I was thinking about using an LSTM model, but frankly am curious what models could be of use and especially ***why***. If someone can explain this clearly, it would be much much appreciated.

Comment: Is $T_i$ a sequence itself as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. The length of the sequence varies per patient and runs as far as 25. The idea is to use all the data available to make a prediction on what the 'next best treatment' is for the current patient (where for example the current sequence consists of [T1,T3,T4, x, y] and we would want to predict x and y.

Comment: So, if $T_i$ is a sequence, that makes $[T_1,T_2,T_3]$ a sequence of sequences, but I couldn't get the same feeling from your example in your comment.

Comment: I totally misread your comment. It is indeed not a sequence in itself. It can be seen as a string containing information about the treatment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to post, not only as comments. Ahd use the opportunity to tell us more specifics, as of now the Q is to abstract